# Why is Visual Studio Code's Git showing all changes on drive?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-git

I am using Visual Studio Code 1.6.0 on a Macbook.

I'm finding that the VS Code's Git is listing tons of changes - even ones that are not in my working folder?

When I hover over these I get a tooltip:

> This file is located outside the current workspace.

Please advise how I can remove all these from the Git panel.

Answer (score 9):

**Here is how you can avoid such issues in VSCode**

- Go back to folder using `cd ..`
- Check if git has been initialzed using `git status`
- If yes, remove git tracking with command  `rm -rf .git`
- Repeat this until you reach your root directory
- and reload your vs code to track current directory

Answer (score 8):

You probably have a git repo initialized in a directory above you. Try looking for a .git folder in each folder above your workspace, maybe on the root of the drive. If you don't want it, you can just delete that folder.

Comment: Remember that it won't show up in Finder by default - look using the Terminal

Comment: Thanks for replies. At first glance that does not seem to be the case. However, I will look again. I know there are .git folders in other folders but they are siblings - and these are the ones that seem to be getting picked up by VSC.

Answer (score 7):

The setting for VS Code is
`"git.autoRepositoryDetection":`

Possible values:

`true` : default. scans subfolders and parent folders of open files

`openEditors`: scans parent folders of open files

`false`: detects only the open folder

`subfolders`: scans subfolders for .git (but not parent folders)

I have it on `false` to work on the current directory.

`"git.autoRepositoryDetection": false`

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answers with .git files in the wrong directory, I ran into this same issue because I had a package.json and yarn.lock in the wrong directory (I had accidentally run "yarn add [package]" in the parent folder), and VSCode thought that every single file in my repo was untracked (1k+ unstaged changes).

I got rid of them and that made VS Code happy.