# Why does VScode keep opening my User folder as a repo?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Each time when I launch V.S. Code, I receive an error message that reads:

```
Too many commits
```

On the source control tab, I see that the directory `c:\user\<arbitrary-dirname>` is loaded as a Git repository. This causes me to have to close the repository every time I open the file, which is obviously a nuisance.

[image: My Console showing Git-output]

Is there a way to configure V.S. Code so that a specific project does not open as a repository when the project's directory is opened?

I checked my GitHub account but I don't see the folder synced as a repo. Why would I even do that?

Comment: Also see [Visual Studio Code Git shows all changes on drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40417795/visual-studio-code-git-shows-all-changes-on-drive)

Comment: The git on your PC has very little (sometimes can be NOTHING) to do with github. All git cares about is a folder called `.git`. That's the "database" git uses. Git does not care about github except when you are pushing your changes to github. You probably have a folder called `.git` somewhere fairly high up in you user directory. Check if you have accidentally created a `.git` folder in Documents or somewhere like that